# Weka using java

Tags: weka

Error: at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1302)
        at weka.classifiers.trees.j48.C45PruneableClassifierTree.buildClassifier(C45PruneableClassifierTree.java:116)
        at weka.classifiers.trees.J48.buildClassifier(J48.java:236)
        at Classify.main(Classify.java:45)

```
basically the run time error is at the line nb1.buildClassifier(train);







 import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
    import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
    import weka.classifiers.evaluation.NominalPrediction;
    import weka.classifiers.rules.DecisionTable;
    import weka.classifiers.rules.PART;
    import weka.classifiers.trees.DecisionStump;
    import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
    import weka.core.FastVector;
    import weka.core.Instances;
    import java.io.*;
    import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import weka.core.*;

 public class Classify {



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

 BufferedReader breader=null;

 Instances train=new Instances(breader);




train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() -1);



breader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C://Users/user/Desktop/test.arff"));
                  Instances test=new Instances (breader);




                  Instances labeled = new Instances(test);


                      double clsLabel=tree.classifyInstance(test.instance(i));
                      labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel);









              }
    }
                  `
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me it can not handle multi-valued nominal class. Try changing type of class attribute or try some other classifier.

Comment: But I do get the result when I directly run it using Weka, so I don't think that it could be the reason

Comment: Can you please share training.arff with us?  Upload it and share the link so I can check it.

Comment: here is the arff file http://axon.cs.byu.edu/~martinez/classes/478/stuff/labhints/tennis.arff